# Cakephp, display field = another foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, foreign-keys

I have 3 models

MasterParts hasmany Parts
Parts hasmany PickLines

MasterPart.php:

```
public $displayField = 'mp_part_nr';
```

Part.php:

Parts display field is another foreign key:

```
public $displayField = 'master_part_id';
```

In Picklines I have a dropdown for partnr's referencing the available parts, so I need to show a grouped list of all the partnr.'s of the Parts table. 
Unfortunately is shows a list of id's. (note: I created the models, controllers and views using cake bake.)

I would imagine Cake would link the functionality so I do not need to write something like:

```
public $displayField = 'MasterPart.mp_part_nr';
```

(which doesn't work anyways)

How can I get a list of partnr's instead of id's?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, I just need to change the code in my PickLinesController by adding the MasterParts class:

```
$parts = $this->PickLine->Part->MasterPart->find('list');
```